# Any clue how to make a circle inside a circle and have an image within the circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Anyone have any clue how to make this in LaTeX? Having two circles and then a car of sort in the circle. Working on some mechanics problems for something I am making. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Car]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site; that's probably why someone downvoted your question. It would have helped if you had posted a minimal example showing that you'd tried to produce the image (maybe the circles and axes?) and then people would be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: In addition to @Teepeemm's comment. I find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (incl. for myself).

Answer (score 8):

Using [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) (user without a MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw  (176,209.95) -- (427,209.95)(298.4,86) -- (298.4,337) (420,204.95) -- (427,209.95) -- (420,214.95) (293.4,93) -- (298.4,86) -- (303.4,93)  ;
\draw  [line width=2.25]  (202.9,209.95) .. controls (202.9,157.21) and (245.66,114.45) .. (298.4,114.45) .. controls (351.14,114.45) and (393.9,157.21) .. (393.9,209.95) .. controls (393.9,262.69) and (351.14,305.45) .. (298.4,305.45) .. controls (245.66,305.45) and (202.9,262.69) .. (202.9,209.95) -- cycle ;
\draw  [dash pattern={on 6.75pt off 4.5pt}][line width=2.25]  (226.13,209.95) .. controls (226.13,170.03) and (258.49,137.68) .. (298.4,137.68) .. controls (338.32,137.68) and (370.68,170.03) .. (370.68,209.95) .. controls (370.68,249.87) and (338.32,282.23) .. (298.4,282.23) .. controls (258.49,282.23) and (226.13,249.87) .. (226.13,209.95) -- cycle ;
\draw [line width=1.5]    (298.4,209.95) -- (251.18,257.17) ;
\draw [shift={(248.35,260)}, rotate = 315] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (15.6,-3.9) -- (0,0) -- (15.6,3.9) -- cycle    ;
\draw (266.38,248.38) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$R$};
\draw (234,149) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {\rotatebox{-25}{\faCar}};
\draw (425,216) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$x$};
\draw (280,75) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$y$};


\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Matcha is surely a great tool for beginners or ones who don't want to learn anything and just get a picture, but look at this code! `yscale=-1,xscale=1` ? Use of  bezier curves to draw circles...

Comment: @SebGlav Hi kind. I agree with you on your comment. Mathcha is a beautiful tool and as you know also Geogebra can export to TikZ and generate the same image. I propose it only for those who do not want to study TikZ and who like to draw. Obviously they and also I do not look at the code, but at the final result.  I give you my best compliments. I am thrilled when there are very good users who write in TikZ.

Comment: You're right, I exported from GeoGebra in my beginnings, but I felt the urge to *know* how to code in Ti*k*Z and I'm still happy to learn everyday in this great community.

Comment: @SebGlav I started about 20 years ago with PSTricks which I still love so much now. I started studying TiKZ after about a year of signing up but abandoned that path. In fact very few questions I answer now. I prefer the math mode, symbols, fonts, and commutative diagrams. They are easier at least for me to create. My sincere and best regards. :-)...from Sicily (Italy).

Answer (score 6):

Easier to understand with pure `TikZ`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        
\draw[-LaTeX] (-3,0)--(3,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
\draw[-LaTeX] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[above] {$y$};

\draw[thick] circle (2.5cm); 
\draw[thick, dashed] circle (2cm);

\draw[-LaTeX] (0,0)--node[below]{$R$} (210:2cm);
\node[rotate=-45] at (135:2) {\faCar};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the simplicity I like about doing it by hand in tikz.